# Replacing FragmentA with Fragment B on RecyclerView ItemClick on Fragment A, with parent Fragment FragmentMain

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have 3 Fragments: FragmentMain, Fragment A and Fragment B.

FragmentMain is the parentFragment of FragmentA, FragmentMain has a FrameLayout which serves as a container of FragmentA.

FragmentA contains a recyclerview.

FragmentB contains a simple layout.

My question is, how can I replace FragmentA with FragmentB when I click the recyclerview items in FragmentA.

I have this code on onBindViewHolder

```
  holder.iv_cardrow_holder_fragmentA.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = new FragmentMain().getChildFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragmentMainContainer, fragmentA).commit();
        }
    });
```

And I am having this error

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment has not been attached yet.
                                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiateChildFragmentManager(Fragment.java:2154)
                                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.getChildFragmentManager(Fragment.java:704)
                                                                                         at com.steven.frio.systemanalysisanddesign.recycleradapters.RAdapterFoods$1.onClick(RAdapterFoods.java:63)
                                                                                         at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5632)
                                                                                         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22306)
                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:754)
                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:160)
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6202)
                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:877)
                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Comment: can you add na image of problem? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is that you are creating a new instance of `FragmentMain` when user clicks on recycler view item. you should use existing instance instead. I think you should re-think your architecture. try using an interface as your recycler view item click listener and implement onClick method in your fragments. then in your `FragmentA` create an interface for interacting with parent Activity/Fragment and in your parent Activity/Fragment, try to replace fragments.
[here](https://antonioleiva.com/recyclerview-listener/) is a link for recycler view item click listener and [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html) is a link about communicating between fragments and activity.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried creating an interface and It worked.

Answer (score 0):

Issues with your Code : 
1 . You are creating new instance of your main fragment.
2 . You are passing fragmentA as argument to beginTransaction instead of fragmentB

use this  :  If you are using support library

```
 holder.iv_cardrow_holder_fragmentA.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragmentMainContainer, fragmentB).commit();
    }
});
```

or use this :

```
holder.iv_cardrow_holder_fragmentA.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragmentMainContainer, fragmentB).commit();
    }
});
```

Comment: It showed an error

    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager.beginTransaction()' on a null object reference

Comment: https://pastebin.com/iC70YDn6  have a look at this. Please read the comments mentioned ...